# Validate Multiple Custom Forms on same PHTML file

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

Validate Multiple Custom Forms on same PHTML file.

I have 3 forms on same phtml file i trying to validate the input fields.
One time one form is shown

**Sign In { if successful}  WriteReview { otherwise } signup**

> Custom js is also triggered on click of submit, but I want to do this with Magento validations.

In /var/www/html/magento16/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/reviewrating/signupformhb.phtml''

```
 <form method="POST" action="#/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="hb_user_login" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); user_login();" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">

 <input required="" id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required-entry validate-email" value="" aria-required="true">
```

..................
    
    ...

```
 <form method="POST" action="#/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="hb_user_signup" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); user_login();" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">

 <input required="" id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required-entry validate-email" value="" aria-required="true">
```

..................
    
    ...
    ........

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[


        var dataFormLOGIN = new VarienForm('hb_user_login', true);
        var dataFormSIGNUP = new VarienForm('hb_user_signup', true);

//]]>
</script>
```

As @Piyush sir told that it validates form before submmiting what i am little bit confused that if i create two seprate objects of `VarienForm` (VIZ `dataFormLOGIN` & `dataFormSIGNUP` why magento mix ids of two different forms ?

Issue: validation work on few fields only not in all fields

Comment: you have to set input name/id different for both the forms

Comment: means name="form1Email"  and name="form2Email" ?

Comment: Yes , try changing id first, if its still same then try changing name too

Comment: sir if i change id or class than i have to make changes in other validations as well, and there are third party API s as well.

Comment: Magento validations works based on id, So if you have duplicate id for input then it will display validation message for the first field only

Comment: means i have to write custom Js than , thank You sir

Comment: what is the use of ` var dataForm = new VarienForm('hb_user_login', true);` than

Comment: it validates the form before submitting, you can keep name same , just need to change id